# What measure is $dx$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

When we integrate with respect to some measure $\mu$ we write $\int f\, d\mu$ or $\int f(x)\, d\mu (x)$. For example for Lebesgue measure we write $\int fd\lambda$, to emphasize we mean $n$ dimensional Lebesgue measure we use $\lambda_n$. When we do Riemann Integral we use $dx$, for example $\int_0^1x^2dx$. What measure is this? I mean "$dx$" Does it have a name?

Suppose we want to calculate Lebesgue measure of set $A=\{(x,y) \in R^2 : x+y \leq 1\}$. Using Fubini theorem we write:

$$\int_Ad\lambda_2=\int_0^1\int_0^{1-x}\, dydx$$

What are names of these measures $dy$ and $dx$? Are they Lebesgue measure? Are $dx$ and $d\lambda_1$ the same symbols?

Comment: They stand for Lebesgue$(-1$) measure, yes

Comment: why $-1$? and not $1$? what does it even mean lebesgue measure $-1$?

Comment: The Lebesgue-1 measure. Just, one-dimensional. I might say Lebesgue-3 measure for three dimensions

Comment: if $dx$ stand for Lebesgue 1 measure then is $dxdy$ stands for Lebesgue 2 measure?